# Prove it has a definite solution.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis

I'm stuck on this problem. I don't even know how to start:

If $(f_1,...,f_n) : \mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow{\mathbb{R}^n}$ with $f \in C^1 $ is a vector field and  $V:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ is a differentiable function such that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{dV}{dx_i}f_i(x)}\leq{0}$ and $V(x)\geq{\left |{x}\right |}^2,\forall{x}\in{\mathbb{R}^n}$, prove that all solution of $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=f(x)$ is defined for all $t>0$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can start by quoting whatever solution-existence theorems you know of, from whatever book you're reading.

Comment: I found this problem in internet, so I don't know what theorems I could consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f$ continuous,
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x)
$$
has a local (in $t$) solution for a given initial condition $x(0) = (x_1(0), \dots, x_n(0))$. If $f$ is Lipschitz, then this local solution is unique. For these results, and for extending a local solution to a global one, refer to any book on the theory of ODEs (for example, Chapter 1 of *Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations* by Coddington).

Suppose $x(t)$ is a local solution for $t\in [0,T]$ with initial condition $x(0)$. To prove its uniqueness, dot both sides by $\nabla V$ to get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}V(x(t)) = \nabla V \cdot f \leq 0.
$$
Hence $V(x(t))$ is a decreasing function. That is, $|x(t)|^2 \leq V(x(t)) \leq V(x(0))$. The point is that $x(t)$ remains bounded. Since $f \in C^1$, it is locally Lipschitz (due to bounded first derivative in compact sets), which gives the uniqueness of local solution.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. And thanks for the referencee. I'm very interested in the theory of ODE's and PDE's.